# Will Nikkor 35-135mm, f 3,5-4,5, AIS, manual focus work with Nikon D90?

Tags: nikon, nikon-d90

Will Nikkor 35-135mm, f 3,5-4,5, AIS, manual focus work with Nikon D90 camera?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lens will mount and operate on a D90 body. However, the D90 camera will not meter with AI and AI-S lenses, so you will have to estimate your exposure using rules of thumb such as Sunny 16, or use an external light meter to determine your exposure.

See also:

- [Nikon Lens Compatibility Chart](https://www.nikonians.org/reviews/nikon-slr-camera-and-lens-compatibility) (nikonians.org)
- [Do Nikon manual lenses work with D90?](http://www.dvxuser.com/V6/showthread.php?147298-Do-Nikon-manual-lenses-work-with-D90) (dvxuser.com thread)